# How to get an applicationContext reference in abstract class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I am refactoring existing code and need to get an applicationContext reference in an abstract class.

Simplifying, here are two classes illustrating the issue:

```
public abstract class BaseCheck {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  protected AbstractConfig configClass;


  @Autowired
  // not called before setConfigClass called so null
  public final void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }

  public AbstractConfig getConfigClass() {
    return configClass;
  }

  public void setConfigClass(String configClass) {
    // fails due to null applicationContext
    this.configClass = (AbstractConfig) applicationContext.getBean(configClass);
  }

}


@Component
@DependsOn({"myConfig"})
public class FirstCheck extends BaseCheck {

  public FirstCheck() {
      setConfigClass("myConfig");
  }
}
```

I can't get applicationContext injected. This code annotates the setter as described in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowired-abstract-class

I also tried implementing ApplicationContextAware, but that does not work for an abstract class either.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Comment: `abstract` classes are not component scanned.  You must autowire the constructor of the extending subclass.

Comment: I was hoping for another way as I have 7 extended classes and did not want to add applicationContext to all their constructors but it does solve the problem! Add your comment as an answer. Any other solutions?

Comment: An abstract class has no independent existence except as part of a concrete subclass.  Spring is all about instantiating and wiring together concrete class instances.

Comment: yet @JimGarrison one is able to autowire a setter method in an abstract class (as the link shows)

Comment: Because setters can be inherited, while constructors cannot.  Maybe @PostConstruct?

Comment: I tried that before alright but setter did not fire before setConfigCheck...

Comment: To "set" the appcontext with that method will require it to be private! (However you can retrieve the appcontext with a public method inside the same class). You may need to lower the variables security access modifier.

Comment: The context will be injected **after** the object has been created, you are trying to access the context during the object creation. At that point it isn't injected and thus a `NullPointerException` will occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the `ApplicationContext` in the constructor. At this point the `setApplicationContext` method hasn't been called as Spring is only able to call it **after the object has been constructed**. You are accessing it during construction and thus a `NullPointerException`.

What you can do is either inject the `ApplicationContext` into the constructor so you can access it. Instead of using the `ApplicationContext` to lookup the bean use an `@Qualifier` and inject the correct config into the constructor instead of using `setConfigClass`

```java
public abstract class BaseCheck {

  protected AbstractConfig configClass;

  protected BaseCheck(AbstractConfig configClass) {
    this.configClass=configClass;
  }

  public AbstractConfig getConfigClass() {
    return configClass;
  }
}


@Component
public class FirstCheck extends BaseCheck {

  public FirstCheck(@Qualifier("myConfig") AbstractConfig configClass) {
      super(configClass);
  }
}
```

This way you don't need to access the `ApplicationContext`. You already had the name in the constructor anyway as well on the `@DependsOn` (which can now be removed), so moving it to an `@Qualifier` to get the correct instance should do it.

Comment: An exciting idea!! I removed all the applicationContext references & I added @Qualifier on all the configs as shown. 

An issue I have is FirstCheck and the others are listeners and another class that starts the listeners is failing as the config class is null. I tried using @ DependsOn for all the configs in the listener starter class.

The code worked before where the configs were passed in the listener starter constructor, but I am moving away from that as SonarQube highlighted too many parameters in the constructor (9). 

p.s. you can't do constructor injection on an abstract class

Comment: You can do constructor injection without issues as long as you pass the reference to the abstract class (which is what I'm doing here). When using constructor injection things cannot be `null` unless you aren't instantating them by Spring but somewhere else!.

Comment: I won't get hung up on that, it's detailed in the baeldung post. 

The @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) is on the method that starts the listeners.... still the configs are null :-(

Comment: Now where did you pull all those annotations away... You didn't mention those in your question also your question thus contains dumbed down code, please provide representative code. Basically a dependency cannot be null the application wouldn't even start with that and blow up during startup with unsatisfied dependencies. The `@EventListener` creates proxies and if things are private, final etc. those will be hidden for the proxy (so please add some actual code instead of dumbed down code).

Comment: Thanks, you have answered the question I posed to be fair for the dumbed-down version.  I used Project Lombok to remove the constructor altogether, thereby eliminating this issue entirely!!

Comment: Ehrm.. Lombok will still generate a constructor, so you didn't eliminate anything adding additional frameworks/generators don't solve a problem but probably even hide it deeper.

Comment: Indeed, only a workaround, have a design fix now.

Answer (score 1):

you can impl InitializingBean .

```
@Component
@DependsOn({"myConfig"})
public class FirstCheck extends BaseCheck implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setConfigClass("myConfig");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I tried this with no effect unfortunately.